# Using a contingency table as input for pROC Package

Tags: r, proc-r-package

For pROC Package. I wonder how can I use a 2x2 contingency table (TP/TN/FP/FN)  instead of predictor/response input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't

The ROC curve shows how sensitivity and specificity varies at every possible threshold. A contingency table has been calculated at a single threshold and information about other thresholds has been lost. Therefore you can't calculate the ROC curve from this summarized data.

[See this answer for more details on the reason why it is not possible](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/372977/36682).